# R Function for Reading an Image from a URL

Tags: r, image, url, r-markdown

I am trying to read a url and get the image from it in order to knit it to a pdf using R Markdown. I've tried using the `image_read()` function in the `magick` package, but whenever I knit to my R Markdown pdf, it prints the metadata which I don't want. I tried the `strip = TRUE` option as well, but it didn't seem to work. Code Below:

```
library(magick)
url <- "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mens-college-basketball/players/full/4280043.png"

temp <- image_read(url, strip = TRUE)
temp <- image_scale(temp, "200")

print(temp)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It works (with a current version of Magick) once you knit your pdf. Try:

````
---
title: "Magick_test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## The image

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(magick)
url <- "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mens-college-basketball/players/full/4280043.png"
temp <- image_read(url)
image_scale(temp, "200")
```
````

Comment: Don't know why it wasn't working earlier. Thanks so much!